# How can I use annotations to customize HLint and mark my Haskell package as Safe?

Tags: haskell

In [my package](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs) I have [several annotations](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/73b6e3c28fcf7394667ed1fe97075c1355788f6b/Crypto/Enigma.hs#L76) to help customize my use of `hlint`:

```
{-# ANN module ("HLint: ignore Use infix"::String) #-}
{-# ANN module ("HLint: ignore Use mappend"::String) #-}
{-# ANN module ("HLint: ignore Use fmap"::String) #-}
{-# ANN module ("HLint: error Redundant $"::String) #-}
{-# ANN module ("HLint: ignore Use ."::String) #-}
```

But when I try to mark my package as Safe with

```
{-# LANGUAGE Safe #-}
```

I get

```
    • Annotations are not compatible with Safe Haskell.
      See https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10826
    • In the annotation:
        {-# ANN module ("HLint: ignore Use ." :: String) #-}
   |
80 | {-# ANN module ("HLint: ignore Use ."::String) #-}
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

while with the annotations removed, I can build and test as Safe without errors.

Is there an alternative way to customize Hlint that allows my package to be marked as Safe?

Comment: I wonder if CPP can help here. Perhaps we can use something like `#ifdef HLINT` to remove the annotations when not using hlint? (To be honest, I'm also unsure about whether CPP is compatible with Safe Haskell.)

Comment: @chi No conditional inclusions in source; ever.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but the Trac ticket at the link tells you to leave a comment if you run into this. The "do not allow any annotations at all under `Safe`" is apparently just a quick band-aid because no one could be bothered to fix the safety issues properly, and because this legitimate use case was not foreseen. If enough people (and "enough" could may mean 1 or 2) complain, it may be fixed at the source.

Comment: Actually, looking into this more, there seems to be a mechanism to use `hlint.yaml` instead of annotations(?). But it's not clear from the documentation how to translate the annotations above into an proper `hlint.yaml` config. That would be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ANN` pragmas, you can use either:

```
{-# HLINT ignore "Use mappend" #-}
```

or:

```
{- HLINT ignore "Use mappend" -}
```

The former will trigger a warning from GHC about an unknown pragma.

See also:

https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint#ignoring-hints